# serialization pattern similar to boost::serialization

Tags: c++, design-patterns, serialization

I have a bunch of classes that can be parsed from and serialized to a JSON object via the following interface:

```
class Message
{
public:
    virtual ~Message() {}

    virtual void parse(const Json::Value &v) = 0;

    virtual void serialize(Json::Value &v) const = 0;
};
```

I would like to implement a pattern similar to `boost::serialization` so that I have to define *only one method* (`void setup(...)`, yeah I know, that's a poor naming choice) in my objects, which works in both directions (parsing, and serializing). This has also the benefit of providing an abstraction layer, so that in future I can switch to a different serialization (YAML? BSON? CBOR?) without rewriting all the serialization code in every object.

So I did the following:

```
class Message2;

struct MessageFields
{
    Json::Value *outValue;
    const Json::Value *inValue;

    virtual void map(const std::string &name, bool *field) {
        *field = (*inValue)[name].asBool();
    }
    virtual void map(const std::string &name, const bool *field) {
        (*outValue)[name] = *field;
    }
    virtual void map(const std::string &name, int *field) {
        *field = (*inValue)[name].asInt();
    }
    virtual void map(const std::string &name, const int *field) {
        (*outValue)[name] = *field;
    }
    virtual void map(const std::string &name, std::string *field) {
        *field = (*inValue)[name].asString();
    }
    virtual void map(const std::string &name, const std::string *field) {
        (*outValue)[name] = *field;
    }
    ...
};
```

and also:

```
// the new base class:
class Message2 : public Message
{
    virtual ~Message2() {}

    // the new method to implement:
    virtual void setup(MessageFields &fields) const = 0;

    virtual void parse(const Json::Value &v)
    {
        MessageFields fields;
        fields.inValue = &v;
        setup(fields);
    }

    virtual void serialize(Json::Value &v) const
    {
        MessageFields fields;
        fields.outValue = &v;
        setup(fields);
    }
};
```

and in my objects, instead of implementing the two methods:

```
// class SomeObject : public Message { public: std::string node_name; };

void SomeObject::parse(const Json::Value &v)
{
    node_name = v["node_name"].asString();
}

void SomeObject::serialize(Json::Value &v) const
{
    v["node_name"] = node_name;
}
```

only would have to implement:

```
// class SomeObject : public Message2 { public: std::string node_name; };

void SomeObject::setup(serialization::MessageFields &fields) const
{
    fields.map("node_name", &node_name);
}
```

except that upon finishing writing this, I realized that `setup(...)` is `const`, so the calls to `MessageFields::map(...)` always resolve to the const version.

To fix this I would have to write two identical versions of the `setup(...)` method, one `const` and one not, but this kind of defeats the initial purpose of writing only one method to perform the two operations.

Any idea on how to solve this?

A solution changing `Message::serialize` and `Message2::setup` to non-const would also work, if maintaining const-correctness is impossible (as I am suspecting).

Comment: make fields mutable?

Comment: If you are going to use a single method to do opposite things then you will need to pass additional argument defining whether it should serialize or deserialize. To be honest I don't see any reason not to use two methods.

Comment: @VTT: if you look at `Message2` implementation, that can be deduced by looking at which of `inValue` or `outValue` is set

Comment: It is weird how `MessageFields` does the opposite things under the exactly same interface, and the those two pointers to `Json::Value` act as mentioned additional argument.

Comment: Someone has already written one: https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/serialization_archives.html

Comment: @VTT: for me what's weird is that it should work as a const method in one of the two operations, and as a non-const on the other (or perhaps this is what you meant), but that should only be an implementation detail to have the convenience of writing a single method and avloiding repetitions

Comment: Changing `setup` to non-const would *be* const-correct, since in some scenarios what it does is not const. You shouldn't expect to be able to mark a method as const just because it *sometimes* does something non-const.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@BartoszKP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2642204/bartoszkp), I dropped the `const` from `void Message2::setup(MessageFields &fields)`.

This required also to change:

```
void Message2::serialize(Json::Value &v) const
{
    serialization::MessageFields fields;
    fields.outValue = &v;
    const_cast<Message*>(this)->setup(fields);
}
```

and to have only non-const `MessageFields::map(...)` methods, which would tell which of the two operations is being done (i.e. parsing or serializing) by checking which value is set amongst `MessageFields::inValue` and `MessageFields::outValue`.

---

Note: I cannot accept this answer, as it is a bad programming practice according to the rules of https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness